# Surjective function that gets every value twice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have built the next function $[0,1]\to [0,1]$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{n-1} & \text{if } x=\frac{1}{n} \text{ when }n>2 \\
2x & x<\frac{1}{2} \text{ and not of }\frac{1}{n} \text{ form}\\
2x-1 & \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq1
\end{cases}$$
I'm trying to prove that this function is surjective and gets every value exactly twice but have some problems in proving that.

Comment: You don't even say what's the domain and what the codomain, so how are we going to guess? Besides this, **you** say **you** built it... so you did build it as to fulfill something...didn't you>?

Comment: @DonAntonio I edited the question. I did built it but there is a big diffrence between guessing it and proving it right?

Comment: compare $f(x+\frac 12)$ and $f(x)$ for $x<\frac 12$ this is the easy part.

Comment: then try to relate $f(\frac 1n)$ and $f(x)$ for $x\ge \frac 12$ (why?).

Comment: In the first case you need to use $\ge$, right now $f(\frac14)$ is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Ill assume that when you say $\frac1n$ you mean only for integer $n$.

Look at the cases where $f(x)=\frac1m$. For example $f(x)=\frac15$, in this we want to show that exists 2 different values of $x$ that will give this value:

Assume that one value of $x$ is greater than $0.5$, if so we know that $2x-1=0.2\implies 2x=1.2\implies x=0.6=\frac35$, this is indeed greater than $0.5$ great.

Now because case 3 is continuous it means that the other value of $x$ is not on case 3, let's assume that it is in case 2:

$2x=0.2\implies x=0.1=\frac1{10}$, but wait, $f(\frac1{10})=\frac29$ by case one! Okay, then the second value of $x$ is not in case 2. Let's look at case one:

$\frac2{n-1}=0.2\implies2=n-0.2\implies n=2.2\implies x=\frac1{2.2}=\frac5{11}$ but wait! $f(\frac5{11})=\frac{10}{11}$ by case 2! This implies that the second value of $x$ is also not in case 1! Which means that there is one value of $x$ is in case 3 and the other value of $x$ is not in case 1 nor 2 nor 3! This means that there is no second value of $x$.